# WebStorm Tailwind intellisense bug

Tags: javascript, webstorm, intellisense, tailwind-css

WebStorm intellisense (code completion) for TailwindCSS is not working, when I start typing something, all the tailwind suggestions disappear (watch the video below).

https://gfycat.com/acceptableflawlesscheetah

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, please vote for [WEB-53365](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53365) to be notified on any progress with it

Answer (score 0):

I use webstorm 2022.2, I had the same issue in Ubuntu 22.0,
I fixed this bug when I installed nodejs 12.22.9